DKIM Validating Signature result = fail, Zimbra Mail Server using Google SMTP
I have a Zimbra Mail Server Release 8.8.15, so using a Gmail Free SMTP. I've already configure the DKIM using zmdkimkeyutl to generate the DKIM Record and Save in the Domain Provider. Also I'm already lookup my DKIM Record using DKIM Lookup and its okay. But when I'm using DKIM Validator to check it. it has result = fail Details: message has been altered. Its Maybe I'm need to use DKIM Record from Google??
Here's my DKIM Record Format
e938d00e-119d-11ef-93da-66ea4b1edf2b._domainkey.mail   IN    TXT     v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=[REDACTED]


is your domain hosted by Google ? it is not clear to me, what do you mean by "using a gmail free smtp" ? if it's a @gmail.com account you can't DKIM sign it. You can only sign your own domain. (and usually it's not free @Google) So please clarify this.
